# Profile views, location section moved to extreme right corner

Tags: bug, profile-page

When I was going through some profiles on the site, I found out some different behaviour in a user's profile. Location, profile views section moved to extreme corner. Link to [Akash.B profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/206160/akash-b)

[image: image of Akash B profile showing change in location position]

However, It happens only for that user and not for other users. It looks normal for other users with low profile or regular users.

[image: Profile of another user with a low profile]

Below is a gif showing the difference of the space taken by "About Me" section in both the profiles and the change of position of location and other details.

[image: gif showing change in position of location etc., in both the profiles]

Comment: This isn't a physics-only issue: I brought it up on chat a day ago when I noticed this on a Math SE profile. Link to chat comments: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46957216#46957216 Eventually, I didn't post anything on the main meta.

Comment: Now on meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316305/long-display-name-without-spaces-is-messing-up-the-profile-page

Comment: @Chair Thanks for your time. I linked this meta in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316305/long-display-name-without-spaces-is-messing-up-the-profile-page#comment1036488_316305) 6 hours ago there.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but can't include an image in Comments...

It's even more extreme on my screen:

[image]

Comment: It's technically possible to put images in comments, though it's rather sticky/difficult. You could go to the imgur website and upload an image (there's no need to sign in to do that), and then paste the image link over here in the comment. Certain userscripts, like SOX (stack overflow extras) expand imgur links in comments into full images.

Comment: @Chair thnx for that! I'd seen image links in comments before, but hadn't taken note of the method used. I'll tuck this away in my toolkit :-)

Comment: You don't need to go externally to imgur - you can just draft an answer here and then copy the link to a comment.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty what happens when you then delete the draft, does the link break or does SE save the drafts?